# What does the single period / dot "." in YAML means?

Tags: php, symfony, yaml, api-platform.com

Can any one explain what a single dot (`.`) means in YAML. Following is the configuration file in YAML:

```
api_platform:
  resource: .
  type: api_platform
  prefix: /api
```

The above resource key has a `.` value.

Comment: are you working on docker? Actually it depends if YAML file is used for linux bases application then '.' is current directory.

Comment: YAML is a serialization language that is used by many applications. A single dot has no special meaning. It depends on what application you are using it for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A period (`.`) has no intrinsic meaning on YAML, because **nothing** has any intrinsic meaning on YAML.

A single period simple means *"a string containing `.`"*.

Only the application doing the processing can give the YAML contents any meaning. As far as the YAML parser goes, the YAML document is valid or invalid, represents certain structure or not; but that does not imply *meaning*.

In the context of the Symfony Routing component (the configuration you shows [belongs to that component](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing.html#route-groups-and-prefixes)), how that specific period is interpreted it depends [on the route loader being used](https://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/custom_route_loader.html#loading-routes), in this case the `api_platform` loader.

This route loader, which you can find on `api-platform/core/src/Bridge/Symfony/Routing/ApiLoader.php` has no use for the `resource` key. It's not used on the class at all.

So effectively, the period means nothing at all. It is there simply because it's a required configuration key for the Routing component.

Comment: Citation on `because nothing has any intrinsic meaning on YAML.`? Pretty sure YAML gets mad when I don't put spaces in the right place.

Comment: @alex That's not "meaning", though. It just that a YAML document may be valid or not. A document may be completely valid (in line with the YAML spec), and yet mean nothing. What "gets mad" is the YAML parser at encountering an invalid document. But what gives "meaning" to the document is whatever consumes the already parsed YAML. A valid "YAML" document is not necessarily "valid configuration", for example. You can put it through a YAML linter and it will come out green, but it could still be wrong.

Comment: In the specific context of this question, the 'period' meaning is simply "a string that contains a period", in regards to YAML. Only when going through the consumer for that configuration `. ` gets another meaning.